Code push server throwing error when trying to send an update
After sending an update using the command code-push-standalone release-react myapp-android android, it does get uploaded to aws as i can see a file uploaded in my bucket but the server gives this error and the update is never delivered to the apps.
Are you using a Stream of unknown length as the Body of a PutObject request? Consider using Upload instead from @aws-sdk/lib-storage.
An error was encountered in a non-retryable streaming request.
Unknown error source
NotImplemented: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented
at throwDefaultError (/code-push-server/api/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:836:20)
at /code-push-server/api/node_modules/@smithy/smithy-client/dist-cjs/index.js:845:5
at de_CommandError (/code-push-server/api/node_modules/@aws-sdk/client-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:4739:14)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async /code-push-server/api/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-serde/dist-cjs/index.js:35:20
at async /code-push-server/api/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:485:18
at async /code-push-server/api/node_modules/@smithy/middleware-retry/dist-cjs/index.js:320:38
at async /code-push-server/api/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-flexible-checksums/dist-cjs/index.js:263:18
at async /code-push-server/api/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:110:22
at async /code-push-server/api/node_modules/@aws-sdk/middleware-sdk-s3/dist-cjs/index.js:138:14

I added the necessary env variables as mentioned in the docs.
BTW, i am using this fork of code push server https://github.com/nmengual/code-push-server, as i wanted to use aws and this fork has this feature implemented.

According to this other thread, the problem seems that either the stream (file) is empty or blob ID is empty. I believe it's more likely for the stream to be empty.
I also think there's no good solution for this, unless you or someone else modify the source.

But i don't exactly know which code needs to me modified.
